# clearTimeout not working for timeout inside an array of objects in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, cleartimeout

I'm creating timeouts with setTimeout and storing them in to an array of objects with the following code in Node.js:

```js
actionSensorTimers = [];

/* -------------- OTHER CODE -----------------*/

let delay = (actionStep.delay !== undefined) ? actionStep.delay : 0;

let timeout = {
    name: name,
    timeout: setTimeout(async function() {
        url += properties.join('&');
        await request(url, function(err, res, body) {});

        let previousState = {
            ...targetIotControlPoint,
            previousState: undefined
        }

        await iotConn.query('UPDATE ' + actionStep.type + 's SET previousState = ?'
            + ' WHERE name = ?', [JSON.stringify(previousState), targetIotControlPoint.name]);
    }, delay)
}
actionSensorTimers.push(timeout);
```

And that code works perfectly: The callback gets successfully fired after the delay, the request is made and database updated. However, when I try to cancel the setTimeout with the following code, it still gets fired after the delay.

```js
let found = actionSensorTimers.find(timer => timer.name == name);
if (found !== undefined) {
    console.log(found);
    clearTimeout(found.timeout);
    actionSensorTimers = actionSensorTimers.filter(timer => timer.name != name);
}
```

The Array.find() successfully finds the object and logs the object on the console (see image below), but the timeout doesn't get cancelled.

The problem shouldn't be in the scope while accessing the actionSensorTimers[n].timeout, because the Array.find() finds the right object and logs it successfully.

[image: console output]

Thanks already for any help!

Comment: That `_called: true` in the log looks like the timeout already had fired when you logged it. So when exactly does your cancelling code run?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you get that object to print out for the setTimeout? I would expect you only to see the id.

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson in Node.js the timer functions act differently than in the browser. From Node.js documentation [nodejs doc](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) you can see that setTimeout returns <Timeout> (Object) whereas in the browser it returns the id. The documentation also seems to be the same for Node 10.x which I'm using. There's actually an old issue about this inconsistency between node and browsers on github: [nodejs issue 7792](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7792).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it turned out that the problem was lying in my loop where the setTimeout code was in. I was pushing two timeout-objects to the array with an identical name-value but different timeouts. This caused my finding-system to return me the FIRST element in the array which's name matched.

Since the timeout I wanted to cancel was the second one, I never got the right reference and was always trying to cancel the wrong timeout which had already been run. (See in the image it says `_called: true`)

I have now added a check to prevent two timers with the same name-parameter to get into my array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

var t= setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello111111111"); }, 5000);
clearTimeout(t);it works !!!!!

As i know Array.prototype.find() return copy of value 
i think you work with copy of object you should work with the same object not with copy

Comment: Actually it turned out that `Array.prototype.find()` returns a reference instead of a copy, so the problem was not there. But still thanks for the answer which made me look more closely on the console output and revealed what I was doing wrong. Please see my answer for clarification.